# How to select single row in every section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards. I have implemented `UITableView` with two sections like

```
Alpha
 a
 b  >
Numb
 1  >
 2
 3
```

I want to select single row in every section and get the value of selected row.

I'm unable to do this, can somebody help me.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Uncheck the previous checked row
    long sec = [indexPath section];
    if(sec==0){
    if(self->checkedIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:self->checkedIndexPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    if([self->checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        self->checkedIndexPath = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self->checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    }
    else if(sec==1 ){
        if(self->checkedIndexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                            cellForRowAtIndexPath:self->checkedIndexPath];
            uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        if([self->checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            self->checkedIndexPath = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set multiple selection = ON for Your UITableView instance.

Answer (score 0):

Deselect any selected rows in the same section.So that there is only one row selected at a time.

```
- (NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    for ( NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ) {
        if ( selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section )
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO] ;
    }
    return indexPath ;
}
```

Comment: Hi @user thanks for quick reply,this is not working in my case.I can select one row only in sec o